# cpanm not working with .gz files

Tags: perl, cpan

Trying to install some module and getting error which it seems to be with .gz but not quite sure. Any lead

Code:

```
cpanm Digest::SHA1
```

Log :

```
! Failed to unpack Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz: no directory
! Failed to fetch distribution Digest-SHA1-2.13
```

Code

```
cpanm -v Digest::SHA1
```

Log:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.6920 on perl 5.008008 built for aix-thread-multi
Work directory is /export/home/ty/.cpanm/work/1371400956.36241464 
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.05
You have /usr/bin/tar:
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.31 ... Yes (6.68)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Install 1.46 ... Yes (1.54)
Searching Digest::SHA1 on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Digest::SHA1
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz ...
OK
Unpacking Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz
Usage: tar -{c|r|t|u|x} [-BdDEFhilmopRUsvwZ ] [ -Number ] [ -f TarFile ]
           [ -b Blocks ] [ -S [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ]
           [ -L InputList ] [-X ExcludeFile] [ -N Blocks ] [ -C Directory ] File ...
Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x} [bBdDEfFhilLXmNopRsSUvwZ[0-9] ] ]
           [ Blocks ] [ TarFile ] [ InputList ] [ ExcludeFile ]
           [ [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ] [-C Directory ] File ...
! Failed to unpack Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz: no directory
! Failed to fetch distribution Digest-SHA1-2.13
```

Comment: Error seems like either it is not able to download the .gz file from cpan OR there is no good network access to CPAN. Check regarding the proxy in your environment.

Comment: Try to make `cpanm` more verbose to find out what is going on: `cpanm -v Digest::SHA1`

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I was able to install some other module from CPAN. Regarding proxy I am behind firewall but ping and wget are properly running.

Comment: @innaM Changed the code for more info. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Seems like `cpanm` doesn't like your version of `tar`. Can you install GNU tar on that machine?

Comment: @innaM can give a try . its an AIX machine though so less chances. Any lead what flavor or how to install GNU tar.

Comment: @innaM Do not have the permission to do so. any other option.

Comment: do you have a gtar already installed somewhere?

Comment: sorry I dont have it . checked it and have very littile info to make anything running.

Answer (score 1):

It apparently expects a different version of `tar`. (One with the `z` option, from the looks of it.) You could always install it without `cpanm`.

```
mkdir work
cd work
wget http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz
gunzip -c Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz | tar xv
cd Digest-SHA1-2.13
perl Makefile.PL
make test
make install
cd ../..
rm -rf work
```

But that means you need to install the dependencies yourself. In this case, that means Digest::base 1.00 or higher (and any dependencies it might have).

Comment: cc_r -c    -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -qmaxmem=-1 -qnoansialias -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN -DNEED_PTHREAD_INIT -q32 -D_LARGE_FILES -qlonglong -O    -DVERSION=\"2.13\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"2.13\"  "-I/usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8/aix-thread-multi/CORE"   SHA1.c
/bin/sh: cc_r:  not found.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 127.


Stop.
 Now looking for cc_r compiler which i checked and its not here. any clue

Comment: it's what was used to compile the Perl on your machine. I presume you installed Perl using some sort of packaging system? You'll have to install the one that provided the compiler too.

Comment: Changed the compiler to gcc through cpan and to gcc but no affect

Comment: What does that mean? Is that even possible? It's definitely not a route I recommend.

Comment: the command which I used was vi /.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm and changed the make_arg to [CC=gcc] but problem seems to be there

Comment: Did you rerun `perl Makefile.PL`? (If you're using `cpan`, I suggest you issue the following two commands from its prompt: `o conf build_dir_reuse 0` followed by `o conf commit`)

Comment: That said, I have no idea if `gcc` is compatible (in terms of arguments or in terms of generated objects), so I don't know if it's safe to substitute the compiler. You really should be using the same compiler that was used to build `perl` itself.

Comment: wonderful suggestion indeed. However I have installed perl5 in my home directory where I do not have root access so will try to make it smooth. Thanks for all of your answeres.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `cpanm` can also use [`Archive::Tar`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive%3a%3aTar). So you might have a chance if you install `Archive::Tar` manually and then use `cpanm` to install any other modules.